# How to implement event sender - event receiver game objects in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have class "A", which will send event "a". Classes that are subscribing to event "a" will react to this event. Other classes can subscribe to event "a" without changing anything in class "A";

Now, what is the most reasonable way to do this in unity? Is there some messaging system that can already do that?

If not, should I make something like EventManager class that will store subscriber classes in array and call their methods?

Comment: you can store subscribers within each instance of class A. also, before rolling your own event system, check out UntiyEvent class which exposes a nice editor for graphically editing subscribers (you can also extend it to support your own types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this.

#### Public static List

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<A> AvailableAs = new List<A>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!AvailableAs.Contains(this)) AvailableAs.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(AvailableAs.Contains(this)) AvailableAs.Remove(this);
    }

    public void SomePublicMethod()
    {
        // magic
    }
}
```

and use it e.g. like

```
public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    // run the method on all currently registered A instances
    public void DoIt()
    {
        foreach(var a in A.AvailableAs)
        {
            a.SomePublicMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Global EventHandler

Or if you rather want to go for encapsulation have as you mentioned a global event handler for all A's like

```
namespace ANamespace
{
    public static class AEventHandler
    {
        internal static event Action OnInvokeA;

        public static void InvokeAEvent()
        {
            if(OnInvokeA != null) OnInvokeA.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

and in A have

```
namespace ANamespace
{
    public class A : MonoBehaviour { 

        private void Awake()
        {
            // it is save to remove a callback first even 
            // if it was not added yet. This makes sure it is
            // added only once always
            AEventHandler.OnIvokeA -= SomePrivateMethod;
            AEventHandler.OnIvokeA += SomePrivateMethod;
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            AEventHandler.OnIvokeA -= SomePrivateMethod;
        }

        private void SomePrivateMethod()
        {
            // magic
        }

    }  
}
```

Now in `B` you would rather simply do

```
// invoke the event and whoever is added as listener will do 
// whatever he registered
// in this case all A instances execute their method
AEventHandler.InvokeAEvent();
```

---

#### Unity Event

If you have however only **one** class `A` which throws an event and you want others to react to it simply use a [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) like

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnSomethingHappened = new UnityEvent();

    private void SomeMethodIWillRun()
    {
        //...
        OnSomethingHappened.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Now you cann easily add callbacks to that event in the Unity Inspector by dragging in GameObjects/Components and select the method to call. (Exactly the same thing is used for the [`onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) event of the [`Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) component btw. ;) )

And you could still add callbacks via script on runtime like

```
public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    public A referenceToA;

    private void Start()
    {
        referenceToA.OnSomethingHappened.AddCallback(OnASomethingHappened);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        referenceToA.OnSomethingHappened.RemoveCallback(OnASomethingHappened)
    }

    private void OnASomethingHappened()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear.*